# Import .eml email to Outlook 2016 with correct received date

Tags: macos, import, outlook, export, eml

Here is my situation. I have emails on an old computer that are not anymore on the SMTP server but are stored locally on the computer. That computer is running Outlook 2011.
I have a new computer where I installed Outlook 2016. I don't want to import everything from old to new computer in order to start fresh. So I synced my accounts on the new computer. But all the old emails I don't have access to.
In order to recover them, I followed this: https://www.macworld.com/article/1156045/web-apps/export-outlook-2011.html
which worked great except that now all the emails I am adding have today's received date. Even though in the .eml files, it is clearly mentioned the real received date. 
Any idea on how to do ? 
Thank you!